# TypeError: command() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, twitch

I tried to code in bot class like this:

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(super().__init__(token='[Your Token]', nick='Hangman', prefix='!', initial_channels=['[Your Channel Name]']))

    async def event_ready(self):
        # We are logged in and ready to chat and use commands...
        print(f'Logged in as | {self.nick}')

    @commands.command
    async def guess(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        print(commands.Context)
        game.check_guess(self, guess)
```

but it displayed like this when I run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Humenoid\Hangman-for-chatbox\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    class Bot(commands.Bot):
  File "c:\Users\Humenoid\Hangman-for-chatbox\main.py", line 51, in Bot
    async def guess(self, ctx: commands.Context):
TypeError: command() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Is there any error?

Comment: and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show the line where you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add parentheses (round brackets):

```
@commands.command()
async def guess(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    print(commands.Context)
    game.check_guess(self, guess)
```

Comment: Square brackets (generally just called brackets) are `[]` and parentheses (or sometimes called round brackets) are `()`. I think you mean parentheses in this answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly: round ones.